# How to hide the src of iframe or embed tag using JS/jQuery or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, encryption, iframe

Im trying to hide the src url for a pdf file in an iframe / embed. Im not sure how.

I tried with all the previously exiting answers, but none of them are working.

```
<?php
    $url = $_GET['url'];
?>

<embed id="renderedPrint" style="height:calc(100% - 4px);width:calc(100% - 4px);padding:0;margin:0;border:0;"></embed>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var encryptedString = "assets/labels/" + "<?php echo $url; ?>" + ".pdf";
        $("#renderedPrint").attr("src", encodeURIComponent(encryptedString));

    });
</script>
```

But no matter which method i use (Obfuscator, php openssl_encrypt/decrypt), the output url is always visible.

I dont want users to find the iframe/embed url. I want to make it difficult to or even hide the url from the front-end.

The purpose is that i dont want users to have direct access to the generated pdf file. They may copy the iframe src url and send it to someone else. We cant stop them from downloading the pdf, but i dont want them to copy the source url from the server.

Comment: You can't hide the URL, as it needs to be accessible to the browser in order for the content to be requested and loaded by the browser. You could potentially serve the file directly from the server side as a BLOB, but users will still be able to download the content locally - if that's the real goal here.

Comment: Could we get to the reason why you want to hide the URL? Perhaps hiding the URL isn't the only way to tackle the problem you're trying to solve. See: https://xyproblem.info

Comment: As a side-note, "I tried with all the previously exiting answers" isn't that helpful, and instead it helps if you can identify the ones that you specifically tried.

Comment: Hello @all, the purpose is that i dont want the client to have direct access to the generated file. They may copy the iframe src url and send it to someone else. We cant stop them from downloading the pdf but i dont want them to copy the source url from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code
you should be add file address to DB

```
        <?php
    // get id to search on DB and get detail
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;port=5432;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //echo "Connected successfully";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT url FROM mytable WHERE id=? LIMIT 1"); 
    $stmt->execute([$id]); 
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    // the address of file in server 
    $path = $row['url'];
    $filename = basename($path);
    if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {
        // get the file size and send the http headers
        $size = filesize($path);
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
        header('Content-Length: '.$size);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        // open the file in binary read-only mode
        // display the error messages if the file can´t be opened
        $file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');
        if ($file) {
        // stream the file and exit the script when complete
            fpassthru($file);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo $err;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'check that file exists and is readable';;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: @Mohammed what is $filename?

Comment: I have been add $filename variable in code

Comment: Did the above code help you?